# Twitter Scraper Twint doesn't return all tweets

Tags: python, api, twitter, jupyter, twint

Twint is returning under the limit which I am specifying.
This is the all the code Im running

```
import twint
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
import pandas as pd
c = twint.Config()

c.Search = "Bitcoin"
c.Limit = 10000
c.Since = "2020-01-01"
c.Until = "2021-01-01"
c.Store_csv = True
c.Output = "../EC331/Tweets.csv"

twint.run.Search(c)
```

After I run that, it then only returns 156 tweets.
Im not sure what Im doing wrong, but it deffo doesnt return the tweet limit i set, as it returned way below that